# Question about Borel Cantelli from Durrett

Tags: probability-theory

Statement(Page 63, Durrett, 5th edition): "Let $X_0,X_1,..$ be iid and imagine they are the offers you get for a car you are going to sell. Let $N=inf\{n:X_n>X_0\}$. Symmetry implies $P(N>n)\geq \frac{1}{n+1}$.(When the distribution is continuous, this probability is exactly $\frac{1}{n+1}$, but our distribution now is general and ties go to the first person who calls."

Subsequently, BC Lemma is used which I understand but I don't understand why $P(N>n)\geq \frac{1}{n+1}$? Is the symmetry referred to this one $P(N>n) = P(N<n)$?, if yes, then the claim means $P(N=n) \leq \frac{n-1}{n+1}$ and I don't why that would be true.

Also, may I know why this probability is exactly $\frac{1}{n+1}$ if the distribution is continuous? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1= \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}P(\max \{X_0,X_1,...,X_n\} =X_i)$ (since the maximum has to be one of the $X_i$'s). It follows that $P(\max \{X_0,X_1,...,X_n\} =X_i) \geq \frac 1 {n+1}$ for some $i$. By symmetry this is same as $P(\max \{X_0,X_1,...,X_n\} =X_0) \geq \frac 1 {n+1}$. But the event on the left is exactly the event $\{N>n\}$.

Symmetry here means that the distribution of $(X_0,X_1,...,X_n)$ does not change if you permute the variables $X_0,X_1,...X_n$

Comment: Thanks! Distribution of $(X_0,X_1,...,X_n)$ being constant under permutation would imply $P(max\{X_0,X_1,...,X_n\}=X_i) = P(max\{X_0,X_1,...,X_n\}=X_0) = \frac{1}{n+1}$?

Comment: No because $P(A_i), 1\leq i \leq N$ independent of $i$ and $sum_i (\cup_i A_i)=1$ does not imply that $P(A_i)=\frac 1 N$ for each $i$. To draw this conclusion you need the fact that $A_i$'s are (almost) disjoint. In our case the sets are not disjoint. In the case of continuous random variables $P(A_i \cap A_j)=0$ for $ i \neq j$ and this is enough to give equality.